# How are SHA-3 variants named?

Tags: hash, sha

How should we succinctly refer to SHA-3 variants of specific width?  The precedent set by SHA-2 naming is unfortunately ambiguous if applied to SHA-3.  Specifically, we have SHA-0 and SHA-1 (160 bits), followed by SHA-2 (224, 256, 384, or 512 bits), where SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512 refer to the SHA-2 variants.  SHA-3 supports the same bit counts as SHA-2, but a different naming convention is needed to distinguish between SHA-2 and SHA-3.  SHA-3-224, SHA-3-256, SHA-3-384, and SHA-3-512 seem reasonable (if clumsy), but I can find no established naming convention of any sort.

Comment: *[There are only two hard things in Computer Science...](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)*

Comment: We don't know for sure until NIST releases the SHA-3 standardization, it will hopefully be done soon. See http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/sha-3_standardization.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they have been finalized as follows

"SHA3-224", "SHA3-256", "SHA3-386", "SHA3-512"

[SHA-3 Standard: Permutation-Based Hash and Extendable-Output Functions](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/examples.html#aHashing)

Answer (score 1):

There is no convention yet. Even the standard itself is not published AFAIK.

I'd use `SHA3-256` etc. (like `MD6-256`).

Same naming scheme is also [used](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/org/bouncycastle/crypto/digests/SHA3Digest.java#119) in BouncyCastle library.

As for `SHA-3-256` and friends, I personally don't like the idea of using the same char `-` in algorithm name and as property separator. If you necessarily need to keep the dash in algorithm name, I'd go with `SHA-3/256` -- similar scheme is used in cipher transformation naming in [JCA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#trans).